Audio not working. Ubuntu 24.04
I am new to linux. I don't know any file structures or any tools. I checked some threads and tried but its not working for me. I have included SS. Only dummy test is shown in sound box.


try F6 to select card

I have the same problem. I tried the blacklist snd_soc_avs and alsa force-reload solutions below to no avail. My system info is at http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=6e472ec7806c6b8218664d7e98faa10c21d18b0e

In my case, I noticed pulseaudio was no more installed, so I installed it: sudo apt install pulseaudio Still did not work, but after two reloads of ALSA I had sound again. sudo alsa force-reload Now, after each boot, the sound is gone. But reloading ALSA twice brings it back.

Latest kernel update fixed the issue for me.

I also reinstalled pusleaudio and only "sudo alsa force-reload" twice works for me after each boot

I had the same issue on my old XPS 15 9560 (Intel audio driver). For me the audio worked fine when trying out the Ubuntu (prior to installation) but not after installation.Seems snd_soc_avs is the issue so blacklisting that solves it for me
Add the below at end of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and restart alsa: sudo alsa force-reload
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
blacklist snd_soc_avs


Try running below command in the terminal (CTRL + ALT + T), this force reloads alsa, after that restart the system,it worked for me,
sudo alsa force-reload


Reinstalling the pulseaudio fixed the issue for me.
sudo apt install pulseaudio

Once done, just reinstall.

Recently ,  I'm decide using linux intead of window , everything very smooth, but i have problem with speaker (not any sound , It work on bluetooth devices and jack 3.5mm). I lost two day to research problem and try a lot of way, but it not work.
Finally , I figured out this way.

Replacing PulseAudio With PipeWire on Linux
let follow some steps.
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/pulseaudio-pipewire-replace.

After follow those steps.
Back to your terminal , run this command.
alsamixer

Press F6 and choose your  sound card.
You need to try turn on , turn off , increase value each field.(Open your favourite song while adjust value)
This way was work for me.I hope it work for you

My issue was that alsa was not installed as part of my Ubuntu Server (which makes sense for a server install). So, for me, it was:
sudo apt install alsa

followed by rebooting the system. (The audio device was not found until I rebooted.) The post by @'tamil arasan c' led me down this path.

I'm running a Dell TB-16 docking station with Ubuntu 24.04, and everything works pretty well, except for the audio drivers. I finally gave up on ALSA and Linux. I just use the HDMI output of one of my monitors instead, that works. I used to bitch about Windows...
